# Is it possible to turn off Internet Explorer Compatibility View in Qt QAxWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, internet-explorer, activex, qaxwidget

I'm using QAxWidget to show pages trough Internet Explorer 11, and it is showing me all the pages in the "compatibility view", although they aren't set in the Internet Explorer itself.

Is it possible to turn that off, and to have the component to display pages in "normal" mode, i.e.  to have underlying Internet Explorer 11 sign itself as Firefox as it does when it's started normally (i.e. not trough QAxWidget / ActiveX Control )

Thanks!
Dushan

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to access IE object model and tweak the mode programmatically. For that you want to start learning [IE API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh828809(v=vs.85).aspx).

Also, I made my Qt project to interface with RDP, you can do similar thing to for IE11.

In your project file
TYPELIBS = $$PWD/rdp/mstscax.dll // replace with the path to your typelibrary. Then you will need to include the resulting header file to your project as well as .cpp one. Then you will probably have other problems better to discuss separately. Or you can look at Qt dumpcpp docs which does the import of typelibrary.

Comment: Hey buddy! Thanks for the help! :)  Of course I've checked the IE API docs 100 times, but I couldn't find anything. Maybe I'm not looking it properly, but since I am a reasonably intelligent person, and most of my time I actually spend checking references (prolly even more than writing code haha :) ) , if you know how to accomplish this task, maybe it would be a good idea to link a function which does it here, so someone who has difficulties finding it, will be able to google it out here :) .

Comment: Unless you use QWebView and don't have such problem... Otherwise, you may want to look at documentMode property as long as "The compatMode property is deprecated in Windows Internet Explorer 8 in favor of the documentMode property."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988(v=vs.85).aspx

This property seems to apply to the document.
See, it is also a general IE question?